# AS3 timer interval with button play, pause and reset

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, timer, setinterval

I trying to do a timer interval that have button PLAY, PAUSE and RESET.
The time interval have 4 section, and each section will continue after the previous section finish.

Section:

- Section A = 2 Min
- Section B = 20 Second
- Section C = 3 Min
- Section D = 30 Second

Example:

1. After Section A finish countdown 2 Min, the timer will auto reset to 20 second
2. After Section B finish countdown 20 Second, the timer will auto reset to 3 Min
3. After Section C finish countdown 3 Min, the timer will auto reset to 30 Second
4. After Section D finish countdown 30 Second, it will jump into "X" frame.
5. During the countdown, user can pause and cont play at anytime. Or reset and start from Section A back.

Currently, I already create the interval, but, when it comes to Section B, its stop to count. This is my code:

```
The `$` character is just a shortcut for `window.jQuery`.
var mins:Number = 0;
var sec:Number = 5;
var section:Number = 1;
var timerInterval;

function timer() {
    sec--;
    if (sec == 0 && mins == 0) {
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        sec = sec + 10;
        sec--;
    }

    if (sec == -1) {
        sec = 59;
        mins--;
    }

    if (sec<10) {
        timer_txt.text = mins+":"+"0"+sec;
    } else {
        timer_txt.text = mins+":"+sec;
    }
}

if (sec == -1) {
    sec = 59;
    mins--;
}

if (sec<10) {
    timer_txt.text = mins+":"+"0"+sec;
} else {
    timer_txt.text = mins+":"+sec;
}

timerInterval = setInterval(timer, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this quite nicely using the `Timer` class. The delays are stored in an array *(in milliseconds)*. The timer assigns itself a new delay value each time it completes the previous delay. The code below should be easy to follow.

```
var delayList:Array = new Array(1000, 2000, 3000, 4000);
var iteration:uint = 0;

var timer:Timer = new Timer(delayList[0], delayList.length);
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, timerNext);
timer.start();

function timerNext(e:TimerEvent):void {
    if(++iteration < delayList.length) {
        timer.delay = delayList[iteration];
        trace("Next: ", delayList[iteration]);
    } else {
        trace("Done!");
    }
}
```

And so in your case delayList will be `[120000, 20000, 180000, 30000];`